# Can't mark checkbox as true in dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a dataGridView which is populated with data from EF database:

```cs
efcontext.Users.Load();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ctx.Users.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Then I add a column to it

```cs
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn newCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
cell.IndeterminateValue = false;
cell.TrueValue = true;
cell.FalseValue = false;
newCol.CellTemplate = cell;
newCol.HeaderText = "Select";
newCol.Name = "selected";
newCol.Visible = true;
newCol.ValueType = typeof(bool);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(newCol);
```

Later in the program I want to iterate through each row and mark some of the rows as selected.
I do it with this code:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["selected"];
    if(something)
    {
        chk.Value = true;
    }
    else
    {
        chk.Value = false;
    }
```

But this doesn't change anything. I have tried refreshing the dataGridView afterward, and also instead of using `true` I used `chk.TrueValue`, but that also didn't work. How can I mark the checkboxes as true?
This is not just a problem with the visual side of a marked checkbox, because after retrieving these rows all of them are false, so the problem is with both the value of this cell and its graphical representation.

UPDATE 1:
I don't need the entities in EF to change, only the cell values in the dataGridView.

Comment: The column which you have added is an unbound column. What do you expect to change exactly, the checkbox check-state appearance or a property in your entity?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I want the checkboxes check-state to change. Because I just have to get the values of which rows were selected and send them somewhere else.

Comment: While you don't need to set the cell template for a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`, but the code works as expected and checks the records. You need to make sure the code is running and also make sure the criteria which you are using is correct.

Comment: I've tried this code. The for part is working for me only if executed after all the checkboxes are added to the new column. Basically I've executed the datasource part just after the InitializeComponent method of a windows form. And the I've put the for part in the load method. But I don't think this it's the correct way to do it. A better solution would be to add a boolean value to your class and just use the datasource property

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have checked the criteria they are correct

Comment: @matteocracco Thank you, that was the problem! The dataGridView binding is in _Load and I have moved the checking loop from _Load to _Shown and now the checkboxes are being marked. If you want to put that into an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you execute the datasource part just after the initialize component and the for part in your load method

```
public YourForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ctx.Users.Local.ToBindingList();
                DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn newCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
                cell.IndeterminateValue = false;
                cell.TrueValue = true;
                cell.FalseValue = false;
                newCol.CellTemplate = cell;
                newCol.HeaderText = "Select";
                newCol.Name = "selected";
                newCol.Visible = true;
                newCol.ValueType = typeof(bool);
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(newCol);    
            }
```

Code in the load method of your form

```
private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["selected"];
            if(something)
            {
                chk.Value = true;
            }
            else
            {
                chk.Value = false;
            }
        }
}
```